# An analogue of Kolmogorov's law of the iterated logarithm

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, limit-theorems

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent random variables, each with mean zero and finite variance. Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$ and $s_n^2=ES_n^2$. We say the sequence obey the law of iterated logarithm if $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S_n}{(2s_n^2\log\log s_n^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}=1,\text{ a.s.}$$

Kolmogorov proved that this holds if $s_n\rightarrow\infty$ and $\vert X_n\vert\le M_n = \Big(\frac{s_n}{\sqrt{\log\log s_n^2}}\Big)$.

Now my question is that, with the same conditions as above and the term $s_n^2$ in the denominator being substituted with $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k^2$, can we get an analogous result to the LIL? In other word, does it hold that
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S_n}{\left(2\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k^2\right)\log\log \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k^2\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}=1,\text{ a.s.}$$

I tried to look for similar conclusions in some textbooks or papers and ended up with failure. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no real difference between the denominators: Let's say the $X_n$ are iid with $EX_1^2=1$. Then by the law of the iterated logarithm applied to $\sum X_k^2$, this sum stays between $n\pm O(\sqrt{n\log\log n})= s_n^2\pm O(\sqrt{n\log\log n})$ with probability $1$.